# Invalid package name

Tags: java, android, kotlin, package

I'm converting an existing app that was made in ReactNative to Kotlin. We want to update the app at the end and not create a new one.

In order to do that we have to use the same package name but the old dev team named the package: `app.something.react.native`. When I try to name the package that way II have the following error:

```
Package 'app.something.react.native' from AndroidManifest.xml is not a valid Java package name as 'native' is a Java keyword.
```

Is there a way to either make kotlin accepting this package name or change the package name without having to publish it as a new app ?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: in android package name start from 'com'     example: 'com.something.react.native'

Comment: native is a reserved keyword in Java.

Comment: @SandeepPareek That's blatantly wrong. The "best" practice is widely considered to be prefixing an identifier for the project with a domain name for the entity creating it, but that doesn't mean the package name always has to start with com (or follow that "best" practice). Counter-example: `org.json`

Answer (score 3):

> 'native' is a Java keyword

There is no way to not change the package name when you want to work with java / kotlin. You could just append something like '1' and than use the replace tool to change it in the rest of the app.
Also all names with '-' are also invaild.